# Java - Generalize different classes, similar methods (without changing the subclasses?)

Tags: java, generics, composition

Not sure if this is possible, but I have a case in which two interfaces have the same method. These are interfaces that are given, so I can't change them.

Given Interfaces

```
interface SomeGivenService {
    boolean authenticate(String username, String password);
    Object someSpecialMethod(Object param);
}

interface AnotherGivenService {
    boolean authenticate(String username, String password);
    String aGreatMethod();
    String sayHello();
}
```

To consume this service, I created a class and did some handling in case this service throws an error.

```
class SomeGivenServiceConsumer {

    SomeGivenService a;

    public SomeGivenServiceConsumer(SomeGivenService a) {
        this.a = a;
    }

    public authenticate(MyUserPassBean bean) {
        try {
            a.authenticate(bean.username, bean.password);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new MyException();
        }
        ...
    }
}

class AnotherGivenServiceConsumer {

    AnotherGivenService a;

    public AnotherGivenServiceConsumer(AnotherGivenService a) {
        this.a = a;
    }

    public authenticate(MyUserPassBean bean) {
        try {
            a.authenticate(bean.username, bean.password);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new MyException();
        }
        ...
    }
}
```

Is it possible to avoid this code duplication in my consumers? I probably will have many of them and wanted to avoid this duplicated code.
I initially thought of changing my consumer to receive an interface that implements this authentication, but as I can't change the given interfaces, not sure if this is even possible.

Is it possible to have a "Generic interface which has a method?" or use some design pattern? Any ideas?
What I was trying:

```
class AnotherGivenServiceConsumer {

    AnotherGivenService a;
    GivenServiceAuthenticable b;

    public AnotherGivenServiceConsumer(AnotherGivenService a, 
                                       GivenServiceAuthenticable b) {
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
    }

    public authenticate(MyUserPassBean bean) throws MyException {
        return b.authenticate(bean.username, bean.password);
    }
}

interface GivenServiceAuthenticable<T> {
    boolean authenticate(T givenService, MyUserPassBean bean);
}

class GivenServiceAuthenticableImpl<T> implements GivenServiceAuthenticable<T> {
    boolean authenticate(T givenService, MyUserPassBean bean) {
        try {
            //this won't compile as it's a generic class..
            t.authenticate(bean.username, bean.password); 
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new MyException();
        }
        ...
    }
}
```

Other problem is how to instantiate this object if I can't change it to implement my new objects?

Comment: Your `authenticate` methods are missing a return type.

Comment: Do you have a lot of these services, or just a lot of consumers?

Comment: Do all the classes implementing the given interfaces have the exact same logic for authentication? If yes, you can simply introduce a new `interface` that `extends` the given interfaces and have your `Consumer` implement this interface with a single definition for the `authenticate(user,password)` method.

Comment: @shmosel, I will have one consumer for each "givenservice".. And I expect like 10 of these and potentially increasing this number..

Comment: @CKing the classes implementing the given interfaces have the exact same logic for authentication, but each "given interface" has some different methods that would have to be implemented by each consumer so I need different consumers. Not sure if I got it right, but by  `interface AuthInterface extends GivenService, AnotherGivenService` it would require each consumer to implement methods from other consumers.. so it wouldn't work.. Is this what you meant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [template pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern) to implement the common functionality in a base class, while delegating the single varying line to subclasses:

```
abstract class ConsumerBase {
    public void authenticate(MyUserPassBean bean) {
        try {
            authenticate(bean.username, bean.password);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new MyException();
        }
        //...
    }

    protected abstract boolean authenticate(String username, String password);
}

class SomeGivenServiceConsumer extends ConsumerBase {

    SomeGivenService a;

    public SomeGivenServiceConsumer(SomeGivenService a) {
        this.a = a;
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean authenticate(String username, String password) {
        return a.authenticate(username, password);
    }
}

class AnotherGivenServiceConsumer extends ConsumerBase {

    AnotherGivenService a;

    public AnotherGivenServiceConsumer(AnotherGivenService a) {
        this.a = a;
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean authenticate(String username, String password) {
        return a.authenticate(username, password);
    }
}
```

Comment: You forgot to extend from `ConsumerBase`; moreover, this would make sense only if `GivenService` and `AnotherGivenService` implementations have different ways/logic to authenticate a user. If they have the exact same  code/logic to authenticate a user, this would be an overkill.

Comment: humm, this makes sense @shmosel.. this is what I'm looking for! thanks!!
CKing, they have _almost_ the same logic.. the only thing that changes is that each `Consumer` calls the `authenticate` from an specific object.. so I believe the only way to achieve this is by using this `abstract` method.. thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is to use inheritance. Then deal with the error in the superclass i.e.

```
    class SomeGivenServiceConsumer {

        SomeGivenService a;
        AnotherGivenService b;

        public SomeGivenServiceConsumer(SomeGivenService a) {
            this.a = a;
            try{
             authenticate(MyUserPassBean);
            }catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Thrown exception has been caught : "+e.getMessage());
            }
        }

        public authenticate(MyUserPassBean bean) throws MyException {
                //your implementation here
        }
    }    
    class AnotherGivenServiceConsumer extends SomeGivenServiceConsumer{

        public AnotherGivenServiceConsumer(AnotherGivenService b) {
            super(someGivenService);//construct superclass
            authenticate(MyUserPassBean);//call subclass authenticate method
        }

        @override
        public authenticate(MyUserPassBean bean) throws MyException {
                super.authenticate(MyUserPassBean);//call superclass method
                //your implementation here

        }
    }
```

then you construct the subclass:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    new AnotherGivenServiceConsumer(AnotherGivenService);
}
```

Comment: `AnotherGivenServiceConsumer` can't extend `SomeGivenServiceConsumer` as they have different methods besides authentication.. But supposing you mean a `BaseConsumer`, your idea is similar to what shmosel proposed.. except I would prefer his, as I still don't need to call `authenticate` on the constructor.. but thank you very much for your help!